# does facebook notify the apps if user changes his personal information?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook application which monitors the change in personal information of a user.
If once i have obtained the access token of a user and gathered his information and stored it in the database..if now any changes occur in the information..will facebook notify the app about the changes in the parameter or do i have to keep polling about the change in user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the Facebook API allows realtime updates! You'll be able to get updates for some types of information: `User`, `Page`, permissions and payments.

Some readings for you:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/managing-realtime-update-subscriptions/

Comment: My app is running in a localhost environment..will it be possible for me to subscribe for facebook updates or i will have to deploy it on a cloud?

Comment: Yes, your app will have to be online in order to intercept the `GET` and `POST`requests from Facebook.